# Why does Flashrom only see the BIOS chip the when Arduino Uno signals are connected straight with 5V level?

Tags: spi, arduino-uno

I am trying to flash a BIOS (coreboot) with an Arduino Uno. The BIOS chip is an MX25L6405D (it is from a Thinkpad x200.)

As I understand it from documentation, all signals must be 3.3V. If I connect the signals (MISO,MOSI, SCK,SS) through a bi-directional logic level converter from 5V to 3.3V or a resistor (voltage) divider, Flashrom doesn't see the BIOS chip. If I connect the signals straight it works right, but as I understand it in that case the signals go with 5V and that may be dangerous to the chip. What's wrong?

With this straight connection, it works:

```
Arduino pin 3.3v - VDD
Arduino pin GND - GND
Arduino pin 10 - SS
Arduino pin 11 - MOSI
Arduino pin 12 - MISO
Arduino pin 13 – SCK
```

With a level converter or resistor divider to 3.3V  it doesn't work. Flashrom can't see the chip.

[Datasheet of MX25L6405D](https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf/646084/MacronixInternational/MX25L6405D/1)

Bi-directional logic level converter (just for reference):

[image]

Comment: I think it might be impossible to answer, but here's two things. 5V logic on the 3.3V memory chip may have already damaged it. Also the level shifter is not intended for fast buses like SPI. SPI does not even require bidirectional level translation, so it is likely just the wrong component for level translation for SPI, at least in your case.

Comment: Level translation is nontrivial at digital logic speeds, I would blame the level translator for the communication issues. Have you considered running your arduino at 3.3V? https://learn.adafruit.com/arduino-tips-tricks-and-techniques/3-3v-conversion